# ML.NET. How to fix System.InvalidOperationException: 'Splitter/consolidator worker encountered exception while consuming source data'

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I fit my neural network define age by photo, I do it as said in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification). I changed my models:

```
public class ImageData
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public string ImagePath;

    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public int Label;
}

public class ImagePrediction : ImageData
{
    public float[] Score;

    public int PredictedLabelValue;
}
```

File `tags.tsv` (splited by `\t`):

[image]

Problem code:

```
IEstimator<ITransformer> pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.LoadImages(outputColumnName: "input", imageFolder: _imagesFolder, inputColumnName: nameof(ImageData.ImagePath))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outputColumnName: "input", imageWidth: InceptionSettings.ImageWidth, imageHeight: InceptionSettings.ImageHeight, inputColumnName: "input"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "input", interleavePixelColors: InceptionSettings.ChannelsLast, offsetImage: InceptionSettings.Mean))
    .Append(mlContext.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel(_inceptionTensorFlowModel)
    .ScoreTensorFlowModel(outputColumnNames: new[] { "softmax2_pre_activation" }, inputColumnNames: new[] { "input" }, addBatchDimensionInput: true))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(outputColumnName: "LabelKey", inputColumnName: "Label"))
    .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.LbfgsMaximumEntropy(labelColumnName: "LabelKey", featureColumnName: "softmax2_pre_activation"))
    .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabelValue", "PredictedLabel"))
    .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext);

IDataView trainingData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromTextFile<ImageData>(path: _trainTagsTsv,
                                                                    hasHeader: false, 
                                                                    separatorChar: '\t');

//System.InvalidOperationException: 
//'Splitter/consolidator worker encountered exception while consuming source data'
//Inner Exception: ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid

ITransformer model = pipeline.Fit(trainingData)
```